# change android system-wide displayed stuff

Tags: android, system, graphic

Is it possible on android that we change the displayed things on screen, out of our program? For example put a color filter on screen (system-wide, not only an specific app), or zoom, and maybe rotate? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it finally! this app uses an activity and sets a transparent image to its background (the crystal leaks!) and puts that in top layer of the screen. I guess it, I'm not sure, but probably it is true, because when screen shows leaks and volume buttons pressed, screen does not show them, because they both are dialog activities. Of course it is just a guess!